Alternate for BEA Weblogic portal
What is the best replacement for BEA WebLogic Portal now that it has been decommissioned? How can an application using WebLogic Portal be migrated to an available alternative technology?
I'm considering Oracle WebCenter Portal as an alternative but am uncertain if it's the right choice.
